# Odoo how to solve error psycopg2.OperationalError: cannot update view "sale_report"?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

In my odoo app I have extended partner model so in the adrees it can hold information about the municipality and neightbourhood of a partner.
I have also extended the the sale_report model, so I can get a report of sales grouped by the state, municipality and neighbourhood of the partner. But when I want to edit the information of the biling address in the website_sale (ecommerce) i am getting the following error:
psycopg2.OperationalError: cannot update view "sale_report"

here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/odoo13/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 234, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 809, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/odoo13/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 346, in checked_call
    flush_env(self._cr)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/odoo13/odoo/sql_db.py", line 76, in flush_env
    env_to_flush['base'].flush()
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/odoo13/odoo/models.py", line 5497, in flush
    process(self.env[model_name], id_vals)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/odoo13/odoo/models.py", line 5488, in process
    recs._write(vals)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/odoo13/odoo/models.py", line 3691, in _write
    cr.execute(query, params + [sub_ids])
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/odoo13/odoo/sql_db.py", line 173, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/odoo13/odoo/sql_db.py", line 250, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
psycopg2.OperationalError: cannot update view "sale_report"
DETAIL:  Views containing GROUP BY are not automatically updatable.
HINT:  To enable updating the view, provide an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger or an unconditional ON UPDATE DO INSTEAD rule
```

here is my code:

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    municipality_id = fields.Many2one('res.country.state.municipality', string='Municipality',  domain="[('state_id', '=?', state_id)]")
    neighbourhood_id = fields.Many2one('res.country.state.municipality.neighbourhood', string='Neighbourhood',  domain="[('municipality_id', '=?', municipality_id)]")

class SaleReport(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.report'
    
    shipping_state_id = fields.Many2one('res.country.state', string='State', related="partner_id.state_id", store="True")
    shipping_municipality_id = fields.Many2one('res.country.state.municipality', string='Municipality', related="partner_id.municipality_id",store="True")
    shipping_neighbourhood_id = fields.Many2one('res.country.state.municipality.neighbourhood', string='Neighbourhoods', related="partner_id.neighbourhood_id", store="True")



    def _query(self, with_clause='', fields={}, groupby='', from_clause=''):
        fields['shipping_state_id'] = ", s.shipping_state_id as shipping_state_id"
        
        fields['shipping_municipality_id'] = ", s.shipping_municipality_id as shipping_municipality_id"
        fields['shipping_neighbourhood_id'] = ", s.shipping_neighbourhood_id as shipping_neighbourhood_id"
        
        groupby += ', s.shipping_state_id, s.shipping_municipality_id, s.shipping_neighbourhood_id'
        return super(SaleReport, self)._query(with_clause, fields, groupby, from_clause)
```

I am working with Odoo 13

Comment: I think you should add _auto=False under _inherit='sale.report'.

Comment: On a side note, it's bad practice to use a mutable object as the default value of a keyword argument.  For example, in the definition of `_query`, you have `fields={}`.  You should instead set the default value to be `None` and then, if it is `None`, set it equal to `{}` in the function body.  See [here](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you change the state of a partner who has sales, Odoo will try to recompute the value of `shipping_state_id` field in `sale.report` view (`_auto` is set to `False`) and that's why you are seeing this error.

This happens because you set `store` to `True` on a related field in a model without a database table

From the [related fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#related-fields) documentation:

> By default, the values of related fields are not stored to the database. Add the attribute store=True to make it stored, just like computed fields. Related fields are automatically recomputed when their dependencies are modified.

The shipping address fields values come from an SQL query, so you don't need to use `related` and `store`, to fix the error above remove them.